# How can I use a custom function in a field widget class?

Tags: 8

I have created custom fields using field,field widget and field formatters.
One of the field I have created is a button. What I need is to write the submit handler for that button.

This is my CertfieldDefaultWidget.php.

```php
namespace Drupal\certfield\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget;

use Drupal;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\WidgetBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'CertfieldDefaultWidget' widget.
 *
 * @FieldWidget(
 *   id = "CertfieldDefaultWidget",
 *   label = @Translation("Certfield select"),
 *   field_types = {
 *     "Certfield"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class CertfieldDefaultWidget extends WidgetBase {
  /**
   * Define the form for the field type.
   * 
   * Inside this method we can define the form used to edit the field type.
   * 
   * Here there is a list of allowed element types: https://goo.gl/XVd4tA
   */
  public function formElement(
    FieldItemListInterface $items,
    $delta, 
    Array $element, 
    Array &$form, 
    FormStateInterface $formState
  ) {
      //print_r($items[$delta]->cert_fqdn);
      //exit();

    
 $element['cert_fqdn'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Fully qualified Domain Name'),
      '#value' => isset($items[$delta]->cert_fqdn) ? 
          $items[$delta]->cert_fqdn : null,
      '#empty_value' => '',
      '#placeholder' => t('Fully qualified Domain Name'),
    ];
    $element['privatekey'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Private Key'),

      // Set here the current value for this field, or a default value (or 
      // null) if there is no a value
      '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]->cert_key) ? 
          $items[$delta]->cert_key : null,

      '#empty_value' => '',
      '#placeholder' => t('PrivateKey'),
    ];

    // City

    $element['csr'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Certificate Signing Request'),
      '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]->cert_csr) ? 
          $items[$delta]->cert_csr : null,
      '#empty_value' => '',
      '#placeholder' => t('Certificate Signing Request'),
    ];
    $element['cert_crt'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Server Certificate'),
      '#placeholder' => t('Server Certificate'),
    ];
    $element['create_cert_btn'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#title' => t('Server Certificate'),
      '#placeholder' => t('Server Certificate'),
    ]; 
    
$element['create_cert_btn'] = array(
    //'#name' => implode('_', $element['#parents']) .'_create_cert_btn',
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Create/Renew Cert'),
    '#callback' => '_certfield_button_action'
        );

    return $element;
  }
  
  
} // class
```

In the certfield.module or CertfieldDefaultWidget.php file, I have a `_certfield_button_action(&$element, $form_state, $button)` function,
but it's not called when the button is clicked.

Comment: I'm not certain, but can't you add a submit handler to $form? Something like `$form['submit'][] = '_certfield_button_action'`

Comment: Thanks. But this not a form like structure

Comment: Are you trying to submit the entire form in a field widget? That seems like a bad idea, and I'm not sure why all of the answers are suggesting to do this. Or are you trying to invoke an AJAX callback from a button on the field widget? If you're trying to add something to form state, this is usually done in validate and setting a value into $form_state.

Comment: No I am not trying to submit form. My requirement is to generate a Key on that button click. I have defined a function to generate key.So I need to call that function on button click.

Answer (score 2):

Because this is your custom widget, you don't need to create a custom submit function.

Just add `WidgetBase::massageFormValues` method to your class:

```
class CertfieldDefaultWidget extends WidgetBase {
  ....
  public function massageFormValues(array $values, array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // manipulate with $values where $values is an array of your fields defined in your formElement.
    return $values;
  }
  ....
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your widget, replace

```
'#callback' => '_certfield_button_action'
```

by

```
'#submit' => [[get_class($this), 'certfieldButtonAction']]
```

and implement

```
public static function certfieldButtonAction(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
```

Comment: I need to pass $element and  $form_state to the function.